# Rails 3.0 member routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource defined in my routes file as follows:

```
 resources :accounts, :only => [:show, :new, :edit, :create, :update], :member => {
:profile_avatar => :get
 }
```

In turn, in my accounts#show view I have the following code:

```
 <%= image_tag(profile_avatar_account_path(@account, :jpg), :alt => "#{@account.username}", :title => "#{@account.username}") %>
```

When pulling up the page I get the following error in my production log:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `profile_avatar_account_path' for #<#<Class:0x7f3fdb166260>:0x7f3fdb7bc4e8>):
```

Does rails 3.0 not support member anymore or is there a different way of doing this?

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
resources :accounts, :only => [:show, :new, :edit, :create, :update] do
  member do
    get 'profile_avatar'
  end

  # or

  get 'profile_avatar', :on => :member
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
resources :accounts, :only => [:show, :new, :edit, :create, :update] do
  get => 'profile_avatar', :on => :member
end
```

Comment: After adding that to my routes passenger wont start and give the following error message: config/routes.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND :get => :profile_avatar, :on => :member ^

Comment: sorry, it's `get` not `:get`, and `'profile_avatar'` not `:profile_avatar`. I put too many symbols :)

Comment: it's always a good practice to give +1 to relevant answers. I'm not begging though

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :accounts, :only => [:show, :new, :edit, :create, :update] do
  member do
    get :profile_avatar
  end
end
```